# mysqld: Can't create/write to file

Tags: mysql, xampp

Mysql is not starting from XAMPP and gives the following error. Please help if any permission is required for any directory.

> 2018-02-02  0:29:34 140735917425472 [ERROR] mysqld: Can't create/write to file '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/mysql/ib0VkQEn' (Errcode: 13 "Permission denied")
>   2018-02-02 00:29:34 7fffa25d8340  InnoDB: Error: unable to create temporary file; errno: 13
>   2018-02-02  0:29:34 140735917425472 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
>   2018-02-02  0:29:34 140735917425472 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
>   2018-02-02  0:29:34 140735917425472 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
>   2018-02-02  0:29:34 140735917425472 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
>   2018-02-02  0:29:34 140735917425472 [ERROR] Aborting

Comment: Looks like a straight forward permission issue.

Comment: Actually I added virtualhost and changed the user and group in httpd.conf. What permission required for mysql and which directory, need to know.

Comment: You can `chown -R username /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/mysql`

Comment: Thanks AbraCadaver. I just did `chmod 775 xamppfiles/temp/mysql` and now mysql is starting :)